# How to parse ">" and "<" in Xquery in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to use `>` and `<` in my xqy pages in Marklogic Server. But Marklogic converts `>` to `&gt;` and `<` to `&lt;` In Query Console also when I write `>` and run the query it prints the output as `&gt;` but I want it to be `>` only and not `&gt;`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **QConsole** you can select the `Text` output format. If you do so with a query that only contains ">", than only a **>** will be output. If you select the `XML` output format, it will be escaped and wrapped in a result element by the **QConsole** `eval` function to make it well-formed.

If you are checking your xqy page using a common web browser, it could be escaping properly written results too, make sure to check page source.

Note also that `Marklogic` returns **xquery** output usually as **text/xml**. You can set the response content type to **text/plain** using `xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/plain")`

HTH